# Running Artifactory on a remote server

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I have an Artifactory local server hosting a few of my android library artifacts which my main android application consumes.

I there a way I can migrate my local Artifactory repos to somewhere on a remote company server without needing to make major changes to the code? I know I have to point my main app's api url to another location though.

Comment: 'remote company server' -> you mean another Artifactory instance?

Comment: Yes. I need to migrate it to another instance and point my local url to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set up the second instance to proxy your local one using [Remote Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories), or you can set up [Replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication) between them and migrate all of your data once.

After you've done any of these the second instance will be able to serve all artifacts that you had on the first (local) one.